# SFDX: What is the limit for number of class names under RunSpecifiedTests that can be listed?

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx, workbench

Does anybody know what is the limit for the number of class names for `RunSpecifiedTests` using SFDX? I assume it will be the same limit as when one deploys a change set either using the salesforce's UI for inbound change sets or using workbench.

Example command:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d src -w 20 -l RunSpecifiedTests -r SomeClass,SomeClass2,SomeClass3 -u myusername@somedomain.com
```

Comment: When you say *limit*, are you referring to the number of test classes you can pass on CLI?

Comment: @JayantDas yes that's what I mean, let me clarify my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few places that a limit might come into play for this:

- **A limit from the Salesforce Metadata API** - The list specified in the `-r` flag will become the `runTests` property of the [`DeployOptions` object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy.htm#deploy_options) passed to the MDAPI. The Metadata API WSDL from my production org places no limit on the size of this property:
  `<xsd:element name="runTests" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string"/>`
- **A limit on the length of argument that can be passed to the CLI** - this seems to be very large. I can't find any documentation of a limit imposed by oclif, the command line framework being used. The underlying node.js/JavaScript limits would seem to be controlling, then. Which is [2^32-1 elements in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36523687/2817283) (ie, number of classes you could theoretically pass) and [2^30-25 characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47781288/2817283) (ie, total characters in the flag's argument).
- **A limit on the total length of the command line** that the OS can process. This will be the controlling limit, I believe.

  - On Windows, the `cmd.exe` command line maxes at [8191 characters](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd-exe-command-line-string-limitation). Your sample command above is 91 characters **without** the list of classes. Which leaves 8100 characters. You could list at least 197 classes in that case ((40 char max classname length + 1 comma) * 197 = 8077)
  - On Windows PowerShell, the max command line length is 32767. So at least 797 class names could be passed.
  - On macOS or Linux, the limits are much larger, in this [2013 Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354870/bash-command-line-and-input-limit), a user says that the limits are "131072 to 2621440". So you could get a few thousand classnames in there if you wanted to.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very thorough answer and probably just what I needed!